# save data from the kinect

Tags: ros, kinect, depth-image

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, im running ROS electric on Ubuntu 10.10 and I want to know how I can save depth and/or RGB image from the kinect?!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11886/save-data-from-the-kinect/) by [bassim](https://answers.ros.org/users/1280/bassim/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-11-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The kinect publishes Image messages on a variety of topics; start by using `rostopic list` to see which ones.

Then, you'll need to subscribe to them. If you just want to save a few images, the `image_view` program (`rosrun image_view image_view`) will show you what a single camera is seeing, and you can click to save a frame.

For more-general work, you should either record a bagfile (see `rosbag`), or write yourself a subscriber node that collects messages and writes them out. See the `image_transport` and `cv_bridge` packages; those will come in handy.

---

Originally posted by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) with karma: 4119 on 2011-11-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use rosbag and record the data as from any other message.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2011-11-10

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) on 2011-11-10**:
Give or take the complexities introduced by image_transport, which means that your messages may not actually be images, per se.